# intellij sdk cannot import ElVariablesProvider

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

i'm try to create custom SpEL autocomplete Plugin,
which is can reference native string as SpEl in Intellij IDEA

like Spring Data Cache's **@Cachebale**

```
@Cacheable(key=#{dto.getField()})
public int someMethod(ExampleDto dto)


@MyCustomAnnotation(value=#{dto.getField()})
public int someMethod(ExampleDto dto)
```

[similar intellij youtrack issue i found,](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-253565/Spring-Expression-Language-in-custom-annotations-With-parameter-detection)

saids that i can create pluings by using

```
com.intellij.javaee.el.providers.ElVariablesProvider
```

but every time i tried, i can't import that class when create intellij plugin..

[in intellij document,](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/api-changes-list-2021.html#intellij-idea-ultimate-20213)

use com.intellij.javaee.el plugin for ElVariablesProvider
but i cannot found it..

is there a way to use plugin or ElVariablesProvider for developing intellij plugin?
sry for my bad english.

Comment: It's not a part of the SDK. This class is available in `IDE_HOME\plugins\ExpressionLanguage\lib\el-support.jar`

Comment: @CrazyCoder oh it works! it looks like i have to put that jar in project manually..

thanks for help you saved my time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out myself.

```
dependencies {
    implementation(fileTree("libs"))
}
```

get the plugin jar direct from the plugin page and added it locally...

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/20208-jakarta-ee-expression-language-el-/versions

[image for intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3yry.png)

I couldn't find better way.

Answer (score 0):

change your `build.gradle.kts` file to above version

```
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "1.9.0"
}

....
intellij {
    version.set("2022.1")
    type.set("IU") // Target IDE Platform
    plugins.set(listOf("com.intellij.javaee.el"))
}
```

Comment: sorry for late notice.
unfortunately, it didn't work 

it kepps showing me error like
---
Cannot find builtin plugin 'com.intellij.javaee.el' for IDE: /Users/my/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/2022.3.2/6a8919a87fd3d40c37c4a5b5ddf71acf042c551d/ideaIC-2022.3.2---